# Create object on IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I'm trying to create an object "lending" on irb to test my database and table connections but I can't.
I have successfully if I specify the :customer_id => 1 on the creation command.

The customer_id field in the database table doesn't settled as NOTNULL.

Could anyone help me?

This is the command I'm trying and the error:

```
irb(main):004:0> emprestimo = Emprestimo.create(:valor => 10000.00, :qnt_parcelas => 10, :valor_parcelas => 1000.00, :banco => 'Bic', :corretora => 'milreais')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Emprestimo id: nil, cliente_id: nil, valor: 10000.0, qnt_parcelas: 10, valor_parcelas: 1000.0, data_emprestimo: nil, banco: "Bic", corretora: "milreais", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

My /db.schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170208154641) do

  create_table "clientes", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "nome",       limit: 45, null: false
    t.string   "cpf",        limit: 14, null: false
    t.string   "rg",         limit: 15, null: false
    t.string   "matricula",  limit: 20, null: false
    t.string   "senha",      limit: 10
    t.date     "data_nasc"
    t.string   "orgao",      limit: 30
    t.string   "tel",        limit: 15, null: false
    t.string   "tel2",       limit: 15
    t.string   "convenio",   limit: 10, null: false
    t.string   "email",      limit: 35
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
  end

  create_table "emprestimos", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "cliente_id"
    t.float    "valor",           limit: 24, null: false
    t.integer  "qnt_parcelas",    limit: 3,  null: false
    t.float    "valor_parcelas",  limit: 24, null: false
    t.date     "data_emprestimo"
    t.string   "banco",           limit: 40, null: false
    t.string   "corretora",       limit: 40
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "enderecos", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "cliente_id"
    t.string   "rua",         limit: 45, null: false
    t.bigint   "numero",                 null: false
    t.string   "complemento", limit: 45, null: false
    t.string   "bairro",      limit: 45, null: false
    t.string   "cidade",      limit: 45, null: false
    t.string   "estado",      limit: 2,  null: false
    t.string   "cep",         limit: 9,  null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  create_table "operadors", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "user",       limit: 45
    t.string   "senha",      limit: 6
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
  end

end
```

My Cliente and Emprestimo models:

```
class Emprestimo < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :cliente
end

class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :endereco
    has_many :emprestimos
end
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, post the commands you gave, the error shown (if any) and your `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: @mrlew I have posted these informations. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the data is not being persisted to the database? That's it?

Comment: Yes. The data just is persisted to the database if I add the cliente_id in the command, like this: emprestimo = Emprestimo.create(:cliente_id => 1, :valor => 10000.00, :qnt_parcelas => 10, :valor_parcelas => 1000.00, :banco => 'Bic', :corretora => 'milreais'). But I think it doesn't correct because the field doesn't NOTNULL.

Comment: Is there any validation error? after you call the `create`, you can call `emprestimo.errors.full_messages` and inspect if there is any error. Can you check this? Maybe you have a presence validator in `client` relationship. Do you mind posting the `Emprestimo` model?

Comment: That's the error showed:

'irb(main):016:0> emprestimo.errors.full_messages
=> ["Cliente must exist"]'

I have posted the Emprestimo model as well.

Comment: One more question: are you using rails 5?

Comment: Yes @mrlew. Rails 5.0.1

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in Rails 5, `belongs_to` relationship now is required by default. It basically adds a presence validator in your foreing key.

You can disable this behavior adding `optional: true` as `belongs_to` argument, like this:

```
belongs_to :cliente, optional: true
```

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference):

> **4.1.2.11 :optional**
>
> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set to false.